# How to use Hibernate Criteria for joining two tables with OneToMany  relation

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I have two tables for which I can't implement mapping `@OneToMany` in their entities unless I have a circle dependency. I want to create a Hibernate Criteria so that I'd be able to join this tables on ids' fields plus a restriction. However, I have a sql query which gives me a result I'm looking for, I failed to understand how to implement the criteria.

Tables which have a **shared id**:

```
|  Table A  | Table B |
|id         | id      |
|languageId | code    |
|comment    |         |
```

SQL query:

> select a.id, a.languageId, a.comment,
>   b.code from TableA a join TableB b on
>   a.id=b.id

Could anybody help me to write the Hibernate Criteria?

Thank you in advance,
L.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it - Hibernate Criteria doesn't support join on arbitrary conditions.

You have to use HQL query (it doesn't support `JOIN` syntax with arbitrary condition too, but you can use old-style syntax):

```
SELECT a, b FROM A a, B b WHERE a.id = b.id
```